# WPF Extended Toolkit BusyIndicator Text is cutoff

Tags: c#, wpf, busyindicator, wpf-extended-toolkit

When I use the WPF Extended Toolkit BusyIndicator in any other application, I have no problems. Using it in my current application, the text is cut off. I have been playing around with the properties on the BusyIndicator. Here is the xaml:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" Panel.ZIndex="1000"/>
```

I wanted to post a picture so you could see what it looks like. The "Please Wait..." text is too low and the bar is laying on top of it. Has anyone experienced this before? I am stumped on what to do. I can't figure out how to change the height of the content inside the box, if that is even the issue.

Edit:

It currently displays as the following:

[image]

But I want it to display without the text being covered:

[image]

The designer displays it how I want it to display but the application, while running, displays it as shown in image one.

Comment: Can you put an image of the result that you want to get?

Comment: @ganchito55 I have edited my post with images

Comment: "Please wait" is a img or is a textblock?

Comment: @ganchito55 He has posted his whole `BusyIndicator` XAML Tag, `Please wait` is the default value.

Comment: This problem is probably connected with something else in your xaml that we do not see. Or is  the code `<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" Panel.ZIndex="1000"/>` making the cutoff problem by itself?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal That is absolutely correct! I posted an answer and I learned something new about how they made the busy indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. The underlying datatypes in the WPF Extended Toolkit's BusyIndicator is a grid. One of the grid's properties were being set in a global style file that I was unaware of...

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that you have changed the default textblock size. But you can also fix with the **BusyContentTemplate**
For example I make the text bigger and red:

```
        <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" Panel.ZIndex="1000" >
            <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="15">Please Wait</TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
         </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

You can also change the textblock for whatever you want.

I hope this can help you.